# AS3 AIR secure socket (X509Certificate)

Tags: actionscript-3, sockets, air

I am having no problem connecting to IRC with AS3/AIR using sockets but when i use the SecureSocket version, i obtain errors like :

```
Error #2031: Socket Error. URL: irc.link-net.org, untrustedSigners
[IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2031: Socket Error. URL: irc.link-net.org" errorID=2031]
```

Tried with another SSL IRC server and obtained :

```
Error #2031: Socket Error. URL: irc.choopa.ca, unknown
[IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2031: Socket Error. URL: irc.choopa.ca" errorID=2031]
```

I read about the x.509 certificates but i don't know how to work with them.

> The X509Certificate class represents an X.509 certificate. This class defines X.509 properties specified in RFC2459. After you make a successful call to SecureSocket.connect(), the server's certificate data is stored as an X509Certificate instance in the SecureSocket.serverCertificate property.

Does anyone know how to implement the certificate ? Should it be on the server side (IRC) ??

Edit : i've installed UnrealIRCD and have it running fine on my local network on port +7000, when i connect to it with Mirc using SSL, i have the self signed certificate alert, i accept it and i'm logged. I'm now trying to figure whether or not this is the X509 cert ?

```
Error #2031: Socket Error. URL: 127.0.0.1, invalid
[IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2031: Socket Error. URL: 127.0.0.1" errorID=2031]
```

Comment: you can't have a secure socket with out a signed cert

Comment: And yes it has to be server side.

Comment: Please read my edit thanks :)

Comment: the url 127.0.0.1 should not be on production. the socket needs to connect to the server host not local host. IE:dev.mydomain.com

Comment: works the same with external IP

Comment: Because when you test locally you are in your local sandbox. Which means you can get data from anywhere and not have a security issue.

Comment: I have both tested locally and remotly.

Comment: Exactly and when you test in debug mode through the IDE you are in a local sandbox which means no security errors.